# エラーは出ないが、マージができていない

Tags: git, sourcetree

sourcetreeの操作について質問です。
masterブランチなど特定のブランチへ、他のブランチをマージしようとした際、
「ログからマージ」から、任意のブランチを選択し、
「マージ結果を直ちにコミット（競合がない場合のみ）」のみチェックを入れてOKを押します。

上記の操作を行うと若干ローディングするような間を開けた後
何もエラーログなどが出て来ずにダイアログが閉じます。

そのままローカルのディレクトリ（変更が反映される箇所）を確認しても変更されていません。

そしてもう一度同じ操作を試みようと「ログからマージ」から同じブランチを選ぶと、
選択することができる…という状態になります。
つまりどうやらエラーも何も出ていないのに、マージが失敗しているようなのです。

わかりづらく申し訳ないのですが、
同じような状況で、何か対策をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: 何もエラーも起きないしコミットもされていないということはマージの必要がない可能性があります。sourcetreeの操作はわかりませんが、マージ元のブランチとマージ先のブランチのハッシュ値等が違っていることは確認できますか？gitコマンドでいうと`git branch -avv`で確認ができます。

Comment: もしくはブランチ間の差分を diff で確認してみてもいいかもしれません。`git diff main develop` のように比較したいブランチ名を指定してコマンドを実行します。